# Python - Problema con while y listas

Tags: python, lista, while

Estoy intentando hacer un programa el cual al darle 10 números, me los separe en 2 listas de forma aleatoria. A su vez, los elementos de estas dos listas se deben sumar y estos totales deben cumplir con la condición indicada (los totales no deben diferir en más de 5 puntos entre las dos listas).

En el caso de que la condición no se cumpla, uso while para que la operación vuelva a repetirse hasta que se cumpla. El problema es que como uso la función remove para que no se repitan los elementos en las dos listas, cuando se vuelve a repetir ya no hay mas elementos para seleccionar.

```
## Funciones
from random import choice
import math

## Defino listas
s = []
t1 = []
t2 = []

## Ingreso valores y los agrego a la lista "s"
player1 = int(input("Skill player 1: "))
player2 = int(input("Skill player 2: "))
player3 = int(input("Skill player 3: "))
player4 = int(input("Skill player 4: "))
player5 = int(input("Skill player 5: "))
player6 = int(input("Skill player 6: "))
player7 = int(input("Skill player 7: "))
player8 = int(input("Skill player 8: "))
player9 = int(input("Skill player 9: "))
player10 = int(input("Skill player 10: "))

s.append(player1)
s.append(player2)
s.append(player3)
s.append(player4)
s.append(player5)
s.append(player6)
s.append(player7)
s.append(player8)
s.append(player9)
s.append(player10)

    
## Aleatoriamente paso jugadores de "s" a los equipos
ingresar = True
while ingresar:
    
    p1 = choice(s)
    t1.append(p1)
    s.remove(p1)
    
    p2 = choice(s)
    t1.append(p2)
    s.remove(p2)
    
    p3 = choice(s)
    t1.append(p3)
    s.remove(p3)
    
    p4 = choice(s)
    t1.append(p4)
    s.remove(p4)
    
    p5 = choice(s)
    t1.append(p5)
    s.remove(p5)
    
    p6 = choice(s)
    t2.append(p6)
    s.remove(p6)
    
    p7 = choice(s)
    t2.append(p7)
    s.remove(p7)
    
    p8 = choice(s)
    t2.append(p8)
    s.remove(p8)
    
    p9 = choice(s)
    t2.append(p9)
    s.remove(p9)
    
    p10 = choice(s)
    t2.append(p10)
    s.remove(p10)
    
    b = sum(t1)
    c = sum(t2)
    a = b - c    
    
    if a <= 5 and a >= -5: ingresar = False 
    else:
        s.append(t1) 
        s.append(t2)
    
## Imprimo resultados

print(t1)
print("Team level: ",b)

print(t2)
print("Team level: ",c)

print(a)
```

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Una solución es recorrer la lista inicial y traspasar cada valor a una de las listas de salida. Luego calcular la diferencia entre ambas listas y repetir todo el procedimiento si la diferencia es menor o igual a 5.

```
from random import random

numeros = [1, 20, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
diff = 10

while diff > 5:
    salida1 = []
    salida2 = []
    for idx in range(len(numeros)):
        if random() > 0.5:
            salida2.append(numeros[idx])
        else:
            salida1.append(numeros[idx])

    diff = abs(sum(salida1) - sum(salida2))

print(salida1, sum(salida1))
print(salida2, sum(salida2))
```

produce:

```
[1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9] 34
[20, 4, 5, 10] 39
```